# Can not disable Webstorm inspections - "Unresolved variable of type"

Tags: javascript, validation, jslint, webstorm, jshint

I turned off the inspections in Webstorm because of this error:

> Unresolved variable of type ...

This is how my code looks like:

```
this.sendGameMessage(pokerjs.PokerCommands.GET_TIME, {params: user_sends = "player"});
```

so this is how I send something from client to the server (SmartFoxServer 2X) and this works fine, the data comes to the server.
Since I once turned JSLint and JSHint on and than turned off again because I got a lot of annoying code style errors I can not get rid of "unresolved variable of type " error.
I also tried to suppress the statement with this command:

> //noinspection JSUnresolvedVariable

but with no success.

Here is an image of my code in Webstorm:
[image]

Webstorm version: 6.0.2

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4):

The `//noinspection JSUnresolvedVariable` works for me. Can you check if the problem persists after invalidating cahes (File/Invalidate caches)? what webStorm version do you use?

Comment: I invalidated caches like you said but it's still not working for me.
It is possible to correct this while using JSLint and JSHint? I mean this because in the SmartFoxServer 2X documentation the example showed there to send data to the server uses this kind of code that is according to the inspection tools not correct
I also updated my question with an image

Comment: Do you mean that this error is only reported when using JSLint and JSHint? The //noinspection won't work then, as it suppresses WebStorm own inspection and doesn't affect JSHint. I'm actually not sure what error is reported exactly and for each variable - can you clarify? The shortcut that shows the error message might help

Comment: I added a new picture with the errot I get. I get this error also when I do not use JSHInt/JSLint or Inspection.

Comment: I forgot to say that I was using "strict mode". now if I do not use it everything works fine... so I think that was the problem

Answer (score 4):

remove unresolved variable in js
[image]

Comment: To turn off these warnings on HTML files of an angular app, I also had to change that setting in the "TypeScript" section